# Is it possible to not differentiate through an undefined variable?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Suppose I have some $\lambda$ that is a function of $x$, and I don't know exactly what it is yet.

Then, doing the following differentiation `D[lamb, x]` gives zero. But what I really want is to not have Mathematica evaluate the expression, i.e., just leave it as it is until I know $\lambda$ later.

Is there a way to achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at `Dt`.

Comment: @b.gates.you.know.what Thanks! `Dt` seems to be what I'm looking for. But how should I actually evaluate the derivative using Dt, once I know what lambda is?

Comment: Please add a specific example to your original post.

Comment: As long as lambda is not defined and you evaluate e.,g. an expression like ex=D[x^2 lamda[x], x] you will get: 2 x+ lambda'[x] (note the apostrophe). When you then later define e.g. lambda[x_]=Sin[x] and reevaluate ex, you will get: 2 x + Cos[x]

Comment: Or just make the dependence on `x` explicit, i.e., `D[lamb[x], x]`  The definition of `lamb[x]` can be done later.